# How to show the requested URL in a JSP error page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, custom-error-pages

In the error page I would like to display the URL what the user requested.

In my **web.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID"
        version="3.0">

    <display-name>MyStuff</display-name>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/error-404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

This will forward to **error-404.jsp**, and here is the content of that file:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Page Not found</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p align="center">
    <%
        out.println("Requested resource: " + request.getRequestURL()+ " not found");
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem it is the `request.getRequestURL()` need to be changed, but don't know the keyword for what to search.

When I start the browser for `http://localhost:8080/MyStuff` then I get the following error:

**`Requested resource: http://localhost:8080/MyStuff/WEB-INF/error-404.jsp not found`**

How to solve this?

Comment: If you looking to catch the error request uri in servlet, then this might help. `(String) req.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple example of JSP error page that shows the error code and the URL of the requested page:

*404.jsp*:

```
<%@ page language="java" isErrorPage="true" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Error page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="history.back()">Back to Previous Page</button>
    <h1>404 Page Not Found.</h1>
    <br />
    <p><b>Error code:</b> ${pageContext.errorData.statusCode}</p>
    <p><b>Request URI:</b> ${pageContext.request.scheme}://${header.host}${pageContext.errorData.requestURI}</p>
    <br />
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Useful reading:

- "**JSP.1.4 Error Handling**" section in the [JavaServer Pages
  Specification (JSR
  245)](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsp-2_3-mrel2-spec/).
- [Handling JSP Page 
  Errors](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahe.html#bnahi) (from the official Java EE 5 Tutorial)

P.S.
The use of scriptlets inside JSP is highly discouraged. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/814702).

Comment: this is perfect! I am using Spring MVC, just in 404,403,500 custom error pages I want to do some "dirty" work