# How to redirect to error page in servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, exception, error-handling

I am writing the servlet , in case of exception I am redirecting to my customized error page for that i have done like this.

In web.xml

```
<error-page>
  <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
  <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

In Servlet,

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
try{
       //Here is all code stuff
       Throw new Exception();
}catch(Exception e){

         e1.printStackTrace();

}
```

But here `ErrorPage.jsp` is not displaying , where I am going wrong can anyone explain me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you catch the Exception and therefore no Exception will leave your `doPost()` method. You will only be redirected error page if an `Exception` matching the `<exception-type>` (either identical or a subclass of it) leaves your `doPost()` method.

You should rethrow the `Exception` bundled in a `RuntimeException` for example:

```
} catch(Exception e) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Unfortunately if we're talking about a general `Exception` you can't just not catch it because `doPost()` is declared to only throw instances of `ServletException` or `IOException`. You are allowed not to catch those, but `java.lang.Exception` must be caught.

Comment: Thank u very much , it worked , & how can I get exception details in my `ErrorPage.jsp`, I mean , I wana display error status code.

Comment: @Raghu What do you mean? `/WEB-INF/jsp/ErrorPage.jsp` is yours to edit and make it as custom as you want.

Comment: not much customized , I just wana display error status code.

Comment: u got my problem . .?

Comment: @Raghu The response status code is available from the `HttpServletResponse` object: `response.getStatus()`. Also note that the `Exception` that triggered the exception page is also available as `exception`, so for example to insert the message of the `Exception`: `<%=exception.getMessage()%>`

Comment: it s exception is undefined in jsp.

Comment: @Raghu You have to define `isErrorPage` to `true` at the error.jsp in order to have access to the `exception` like this (you may change other parts, this is just an example): `<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*" contentType="text/html"%>`

Answer (score 2):

You're catching the exception, and only printing the stacktrace inside, so the error-page doesn't take affect, remove the try-catch or re-throw and it will work. In addition, you have some syntax errors. Try something like

```
try{
       //Here is all code stuff
       throw new Exception();
}catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         throw new ServletException();
}
```

Comment: k . . Thank u , I got the solution  & do u know how can I got exception details in `ErrorPage.jsp`? I mean , I wana display error status code.

Answer (score 1):

You have handled the `Exception` in your `doPost()` using ,

```
try{
       //Here is all code stuff
       Throw new Exception();
}catch(Exception e){
         e1.printStackTrace();    
}
```

`try` and `catch` blocks. so the `errorPage.jsp` will not be invoked. `<error-page>` is invoked for unhandled exceptions

A nice example tutorial [Exception Handling](http://www.journaldev.com/1973/servlet-exception-and-error-handling-example-tutorial)

Read for more info [Best practice error handling in JSP Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20383185/best-practice-error-handling-in-jsp-servlets)

Comment: Thank u . . , the tutorial really helps me . .